# Jenkins - Build Pipeline - Showing unwanted Job after using Join Plug

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, build-automation, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to set up Jenkins as follows:

Test Job --> (Test Job 1 & Test Job 2 in parallel) --> Test Job 3 --> Test Job 4

I have this working at present using the Join Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) and Build Pipeline Plugin.

However the display on the Build Pipeline unnecessarily 2 x Test Job 3s and 2 x Test Job 4s after the join, see below:

[image]

Set up for each job is as follows:

**Test Job:**
[image]

**Test Job 1 & 2:**
[image]

**Test Job 3:**

[image]

**Test Job 4:**

[image]

I would like to remove the "blue" versions of Test Job 3 and Test Job 4 from my Build Pipeline after the two parallel processes finish.

Anybody able to help me to remove these?

Cheers

Comment: I'm using the [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) for a similar use case without problems. Give it a try ;)

Comment: This incompatibility between the Join and the Build Pipeline plugins has already been reported as [Jenkins bug 18464](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18464)

Answer (score 2):

Try with [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)

It will do both parallel and sequential jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) alone without the [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin).

The [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) gives you the functionality of the [Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin), and its configuration is more straightforward.  I actually prefer how it displays my running build.

You can put a multijob into a build pipeline, but the placement of the jobs within the pipeline is wrong  The jobs within the multijob are displayed in *vertically* in *alphabetical order* (not build order).  On the positive side, everything else seems to work, so this should be easy to fix.  I reported this problem as [Jenkins bug 22074](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22074).

Answer (score 0):

the 'Jenkins - Build Pipeline' plugin support customize css , maybe you could make it unvisable by css

Answer (score 0):

You can use build pipeline plugin together with Multijob plugin. Just use Multijob plugin as a substitute for Join plugin. Basically, Multijob plugin will only be used to make certain jobs to be executed simultaneously.

If you do this way, then build Pipeline view won't get screwed up.

### This is how it looks in Pipeline Build view

[image]

1. build-bv-docker-images is a Multijob plugin Job.
2. build-(activemq|postgres|tomcat|wildfly)-bv_image are simple jobs used for building docker images
3. deploy-staging is a job, which is triggered after build-bv-docker-images job. Logically speaking it suppose to appear right after stack of build-*-bv-images jobs, but it appears as a part of this stack. Nevertheless, it's waiting until all jobs of this stack are completed. *I had to prefix deploy-staging job with + sign in order to make it appear on the top of the stack*. It looks awkward, but it's still better than to see deploy-staging job in the bottom of the stack.

**This is how build-bv-docker-images multijob is configured**
[image]

Comment: this is a low quality answer.